# Horizontal auto scaler doesn't report CPU usage

Tags: kubernetes, heapster

I am trying to test the Kubernetes HPA like in example [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/)

```
kubectl run php-apache --image=gcr.io/google_containers/hpa-example --requests=cpu=200m --expose --port=80
kubectl autoscale deployment php-apache --cpu-percent=20 --min=1 --max=10
kubectl get hpa
```

output is

```
NAME         REFERENCE               TARGETS           MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
php-apache   Deployment/php-apache   <unknown> / 20%   1         3         0          1h
```

**Why isn't controller-manager able to get current usage?**

---

**Environment details :**

- K8s version 1.7.3 with Heapster running with a service on port 80, in
  kube-system.
- InfluxDB is set as sink and I can see the usage/limit
  etc. correctly in Grafana as well as on Heapster API
- I can see the cpu requests (200m) on the deployed pod's yaml.
- No errors in controller manager logs. All I see is etcd watch and pod creation messages.
- There is no "horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period" specified in controller manifest, default should be 30 seconds.
- "hpa describe" doesn't list any events ("<none>").
- Creating/deleting HPA doesn't create any log in controller-manager
- When I didn't have Heapster installed, controller-manager logs would complain. I do not see this message with Heapster installed : "

> failed to compute desired number of replicas based on listed metrics
>   for Deployment/xx/php-apache: failed to get cpu utilization: unable to
>   get metrics for resource cpu: failed to get pod resource metrics: the
>   server cannot complete the requested operation at this time, try again
>   later (get services http:heapster:)

---

**Edit 1 [14-Sep] :**

- I have uploaded the [Heapster logs here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4hwpntek2712v9k/heapster_logs.txt?dl=0). No errors there.
- I checked the Heapster API directly for metrics, and I get response.

  `curl http://10.107.55.59/api/v1/model/namespaces/cp/pods/php-apache-593471247-c65fh/metrics/cpu/usage`

`{
  "metrics": [
   {
    "timestamp": "2017-09-14T13:46:00Z",
    "value": 19008838
   },
   {
    "timestamp": "2017-09-14T13:47:00Z",
    "value": 19008838
   },
   {
    "timestamp": "2017-09-14T13:48:00Z",
    "value": 19008838
   }
  ],
  "latestTimestamp": "2017-09-14T13:48:00Z"
 }`

[image: Grafana Screenshot for the pod. No limit was set, but that doesn't make any difference either.]

Answer (score 0):

Validate if heapster is fetching data and giving metric, try to run below on kube-api server, replace namespace-name and pod-name in it. it will show metric, if all well, also paste heapster log here

curl http://localhost:8080/api/v1/model/namespaces/{namespace-name}/pods/{pod-name}/metrics/